# como renderizar un array de components, nextjs

Tags: array, reactjs, component, nextjs

quería saber como puedo hacer un array de componentes, ya que he hecho varias pruebas sencillas y no me funciona como esperaba. He buscado por internet pero me salen ejemplos que no tienen que ver con lo que quiero hacer, si me pueden orientar y guiarme a una documentacion al respecto pues se los agradezco; sin mas les explico un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:

```
import component1 from "./component1"
import component2 from "./component2"

export default function Page(){
const [list, setList] = useState([])

return 
(<div>
<button onClick={e => setList(component1)}>
component 1
</button>
<button onClick={e => setList(component2)}>
component 2
</button>
<div id="content">
{list.map(component => component)}
</div>
</div>)
}
```

básicamente lo que quiero lograr es agregar un componente a una lista para luego imprimirlos con map(), al darle clic debería agregarse un componente a la lista y poder imprimir luego estos componentes seleccionados, no se como empezar a hacerlo y lo que he intentado es parecido a lo que escribí de ejemplo pero no me ha funcionado, los ejemplos de internet solo son con string y objetos, aun no he logrado conseguir alguna guia que me ayude a entender ese funcionamiento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un elemento a un arreglo puedes utilizar `setList([...list, component1])`. En este caso los elementos son componentes, de modo que, en el método map puedes utilizarlos de manera similar a un componente `<Component />`. Por último para ver cambios instantáneos puedes utilizar `useEffect()`.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

import component1 from "./component1"
import component2 from "./component2"

export default function Page() {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [list])

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setList([...list, component1])}>
                component 1
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setList([...list, component2])}>
                component 2
            </button>
            <div id="content">
                {list.map((Component, index) => {
                    return <Component key={index} />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu ejemplo, me ayudo a darme cuenta que el problema que tenia era en el return del div#content y el useeffect no lo habia tomado en cuenta